# logstash configuration file for MongoDB json array

Tags: json, mongodb, logstash, elastic-stack

I am completely new to the ELK stack. Have installed all the technologies I would like to write a logstash configuration file to get the data from my mongo database, output it in elastic search and create a dashboard using kibana. Below is a sample of a single json document within my array:

```
{
    "ComputerName": "DWP0020",
    "Health": "Online",
    "ClientVersion": "12.1.4112.4156",
    "VirusDefinitions": "23/03/2016 r32",
    "SONARDefinitions": "12/03/2016 r13",
    "IPSSignatures": "23/03/2016 r11",
    "DownloadProtectionContent": "23/03/2016 r1",
    "LastStatusChange": "21/07/2016 13:40",
    "OS": "Windows 7 Edition",
    "ProcessorType": "x86 Family 20 Model 2 Stepping 0",
    "Memory": "Total: 1.62 gb",
    RemainingMemory: "Free: 17.5 gb",
    "DiskSpace": "Total: 29.5 gb"
  }
```

In terms of the filter within the configuration, I would like kibana to display devices, which haven't changed status the longest. Have remaining less than 10MB and a pie chart showing the percentage with specific virus definitions.

Any useful sources/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Getting info from MongoDB into ELK can be tricky. Not sure if you've seen this, but [this post](http://logz.io/blog/mongodb-performance-monitoring-elk-stack/) explains how to extract perf metrics from mongo into ELK. Hope it helps.